# Unable to solve Dell.Client.Framework.UserProcess.exe error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

[image]

This error occurred after I updated the Visual Studio 2019 version from 16.11.19 to 16.11.27.
I have tried to click yes, however nothing is being downloaded.

Also, before installing new VS version, I have been aware of the warning below.

[image]

Hence, I installed related .NET that pop up during new version installation but seems the error still not solved. Can I know how to proceed solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

The message shown in the second picture seems to have nothing to do with the error message shown in the first picture.
Figure 2 just reminds you that .NET Core 3.1 and .NET SDK have been "out of support".

Now it is necessary to solve the issue in Figure 1. This should be when opening an exe because the computer does not have a corresponding operating environment, you can download and install the .net version corresponding to the exe target framework from this website: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet